Is there some criterion for a divisor in the restricted base locus will always be contracted by the minimal model program?
Let $(X,B)$ be a KLT pair, which is of log general type, that we can run MMP with scaling $H$ by BCHM and gets $\phi:(X,B)\dashrightarrow (X^m,B^m)$.
The question is: Is there some criterion that the minimal model program $\phi$ will contract the divisor $E$ if it lies in the restricted base locus of the log canonical divisor?

Where we define the stable divisorial base locus to be $$\mathbf{B}^{\text{div}}(D) = \lim_{m\to \infty} B^{\text{div}}(\lfloor{md}\rfloor)$$
where $B^{\text{div}}$denotes the divisorial part of the base locus. And the restriected base locus for a divisor $D$ is defined to be $$\textbf{B}_-^{\text{div}}(D) = \sup_{A\in \mathcal{I}}\textbf{B}^{\text{div}}(D+A)$$for $\mathcal{I} = \{A\text{ is big }\mathbb{R}\text{-divisor s.t. }\textbf{B}^{\text{div}}(A) = \emptyset\}$

It is easy to see that $\phi$ contracts precisely the divisors in $\mathbf B^{div}(K_X+B)=\mathbf B^{div}-(K_X+B)$. By [BCHM], $K{X^m}+B^m$ and $K_{X^m}+B^m+tH^m$ are nef and big hence semiample (for $0<t\ll 1$). Let $p:W\to X$ and $q:W\to X^m$ be a common resolution, then $p^(K_X+B)=q^(K_{X^m}+B^m)+E$ where $E$ is $q$-exceptional and $p_*E$ is the set of $\phi$-exceptional divisors. Thus $\mathbf B^{div}(K_X+B)=p_*E$ is the set of $\phi$-exceptional divisors (similarly for $\mathbf B^{div}_-(K_X+B)$).

Dear Professor @Hacon , I realize that this is precisely the Nakamaye’s base locus theorem and the divisor being contracted are the divisorial part of the null locus, is my understanding correct?

I think Nakamaye’s base locus theorem says that if $D$ is nef, then $\mathbb B -(D)={\rm Null}(D)$. I am not using this (even though it is somewhat related. I am using a few things: 1) the mmp terminates after finitely many steps implies that there is a $t_0>0$ such that $K{X^m}+B^m+tH^m$ is nef for $0\leq t\leq t_0$, 2) the base point free thm tells us that $K_{X^m}+B^m+tH^m$ is semiample for $0\leq t\leq t_0$ and 3) $\phi$ is $K_{X^m}+B^m+tH^m$ non-positive for $0\leq t\leq t_0$ and neg. wrt to the contracted divisors so that $p^(K_X+B)=q^(K_{X^m}+B^{m})+E$ where $E\geq 0$ etc..

For stable base locus $\textbf{B}^{div}(K_X+B)$
As Professor Hacon points out by the standard results of minimal model theory and BCHM we have 3 essential facts given in the comments.
The key point is to apply the following lemma developed by Professor Mckernan (the original one is stated in curves but it does not change if replace curve by divisor) see Lemma 3.1.)

Lemma 3.1. Let $S$ and $Y$ be normal projevtive varieties, let $D$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-Cartier divisor on $S$ and let $T \subset S$ be a divisor. Let $\phi: S \dashrightarrow Y$ be a $D$-negative birational map.
Let $p: W \longrightarrow S$ and $q: W \longrightarrow Y$ be proper birational morphisms which resolve $\phi$. Let $Z$ be the indeterminancy locus of $\phi^{-1}$.
At least one of the following holds:
(1) $T \subset p\left(q^{-1}(Z)\right)$ , or
(2) Every divisor $\Sigma \subset Y$ such that $T \subset p\left(q^{-1}(\Sigma)\right)$ belongs to the stable base locus of $\phi_* D$, or
(3) $T$ does not belong to the stable base locus of $D$.

Set $D = K_X+B$ and since $K_{X^m}+B^m$ is semi-ample the stable base locus is empty, (2) can not hold. By assumption we want to consider divisors lie in the stable base locus (3) can not hold. And the only possibility is (1) that is those divisors in $\textbf{B}(K_X+B)$ must being contracted.
For the restricted base locus $\textbf{B}_{-}^{div}(K_X+B)$
By definition $$\textbf{B}_-^{div}(K_X+B) = \bigcup_{\epsilon>0}\textbf{B}^{div}({K_X+B+\epsilon H})$$
Now every divisor in the stable base locus $\textbf{B}^{div}({K_X+B+\epsilon H})$ for $0 \le\epsilon <t_0$ we already proved it in Case 1, and result is clear.
Few remarks
(1) By the main theorem by Boucksom, Broustet, and Pacienza one has $$\text{NNef}(K_X+B) = \mathbf B^{div}(K_X+B)=\mathbf B^{div}_-(K_X+B)
$$that's what Professor Hacon writes in the first sentence.
(2) The restricted base locus is empty iff the divisor is nef. We see immediately that once we hit the minimal model, the restricted base locus (nonnef locus) becomes empty there is nothing to contract anymore.
(3) Relation between Zariski decomposition: On a smooth surface for a big divisor $K_X+B$ we can take Zariski decomposition $K_X+B = P +N$ and we can show in this case $$\textbf{B}_-^{div}(K_X+B) = \text{supp}(N),\quad \textbf{B}_+^{div}(K_X+B) = \text{Null}(P)$$
(see e.g. Asymptotic invariants of base loci) and we know the negative part (rigid part) is exceptionals.
